# Invariant Subspace of Vertex Representation of $D_4$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

I am looking at the vertex permutation representation of $D_4$ in $\mathbb R^4,$ where the vertices of the square are labelled $1,2,3,$ and $4.$  How do I prove that this representation has proper invariant subspaces?

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb R^\color{red}2$?

Comment: This is the rep where the permutation matrices are 4 x 4 not the 2 x 2 irrep.  I proved that case for 1 - dimension by noting that after a rotation a vector does not go back to itself etc.

Answer (score 1):

The constant vectors form an invariant subspace.

Comment: OK, I had thought that I could relabel the vertices to (1 + 2 + 3 + -6) = 0 and find the null space of  (1 1 1 1) to get a basis of (-1 1 0 0), (-1 0 1 0) and (-1 0 0 1).  Is this valid?

Comment: @user1884367: What do you mean by "relabeling the vertices to $(1+2+3+-6)=0$"?

Comment: Yes not explained too well.. This idea came from [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/rep.pdf) page 29.

Comment: @user1884367: I'm afraid I don't see how what you write relates to what's written there. Also I don't understand why you asked your question if you already had this text; it already proves that the representation has proper invariant subspaces.